# How to inject Mock Request Headers when using Apnet WebForms?

Tags: webforms, http-headers

Is there any way to inject 'Mock' Request Headers for testing purposes when using Aspnet WebForms? I'm able to do this in my .NET CORE Projects using Middleware, but now I'd like to help a customer do the same thing with their Webforms project. I haven't worked with WebForms in many years, and I haven't found much online about this so far. I'm just looking for a starting point so I can investigate further. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found Something here - will update later with my solution:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpprotocol/customheaders/